# WebView and onPause()

Tags: android, webview, onpause

I am using a ListView which uses a WebView as a list item. To clear memory I am destroying the detached views by calling `webview.destory()` once  `webview.visibiliy == GONE`  is true.

But the problem is that  `webview.visibiliy == GONE`  becomes true if `onPause()` is called due to any action or activity because the condition is true for the webview if there is an activity switch.

Is there a way like :

```
if (onPauseiscalled() == true){
         //do something
}
```

PS: I've tried creating an object of the class and accessing the methods, but I think it does not seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, but it's when your application has been paused (and not specifically your webView):

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Another activity is taking focus (this activity is about to be "paused").
}
```

I'm not sure if this works but never the less:

```
public class CustomWebView extends WebView {
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```